# What's the right way to allow systemd-timesyncd through iptables firewall?

Tags: iptables, ntp

First, I set up my firewall like this to allow everything:

```sh
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables --flush
```

Then, I check if NTP is working:

```sh
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd
timedatectl
```

and I can see that it says `System clock synchronized: yes`.

But then if I reboot and set up my firewall like this (reject everything except for NTP):

```sh
sudo iptables -P INPUT REJECT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT REJECT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD REJECT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
```

then I get `System clock synchronized: no` and the clock won't sync.

Based on the above steps, I'm convinced it's the firewall that's blocking timesyncd. I have read (for example, [here](https://serverfault.com/q/1064319/359498)) that perhaps it has to do with extra ports being opened by the service or the fact that is uses SNTP instead of NTP. I have tried different combinations of rules, but with no success yet as I am not an expert with iptables.

But there must be a way to set it up such that it works without altogether disabling the firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Summary

`--dport` and `--sport` are switched.

### Explanation

For the other services that I am allowing through the firewall, my machine is the *server*. For NTP, my machine is the *client*. Because the rest of my original configuration actually looked more like this:

```sh
...
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
...
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 5353 -j ACCEPT
...
```

I assumed that `--dport` was meant to be used with `INPUT` and `--sport` was used with `OUTPUT`. However, you have to think about what it means. To use NTP as a client, I need to allow *INPUT* packets that are coming from a *source* port of 123, not input packets that are coming to a destination port of 123. Likewise, I need to allow *OUTPUT* packets with *destination* port 123, not output with source 123.

So the answer to my question is to use this:

```sh
sudo iptables -P INPUT REJECT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT REJECT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD REJECT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
```